# Having Problem in provider package in flutter

Tags: generics, flutter, dart, provider

This is the error showing
[Error is showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DoFs.png)

And this is the code 
[flutter provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Vyy8.png)

how to solve this

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: You should explain the problem in the question itself, explain what you tried, and include the code rather than a link to the code/error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message explains, in order to call Provider.of, you need to actually have a provider widget as an ancestor in that context. When you declare your provider widget, you need to declare the "create" field so that what is being provided is actually instantiated and associated with that context.

More info is under "usage" here:

https://pub.dev/packages/provider

Comment: Thank you Kris it help me, I have forgot to assign the "ChangeNotifierProvider" inside the main.dart file. Thanks dude.